# how can I improve my code to generate secure random numbers?

Tags: c++, windows, random

I am trying to found out what is the best way or library to generate secure random numbers such as `secrets` in python.

I am working on windows 10 using codeblocks. 
I have done this so far:

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <ctime> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{ 
    srand((unsigned)time(0)); 
    int i;
    i = (rand()%6)+1; 
    cout << i << "\n"; 
}
```

I am trying to replicate the same function as `secrets` from python to generate secure random numbers.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with what's in the C++ STL now, but is this not still platform specific? (I.e. `CryptGenRandom`/`/dev/(u)random`)

Comment: I don't think standard C++ provides a cryptographically secure random generator, but you should take a look at C++ [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library. Perhaps it will be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Some very educational humour for your day: Lavavej's [rand() Considered Harmful presentation](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).

Answer (score 5):

[`std::rand()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/rand) does not offer sufficient guarantees for being used in cryptographic applications (aka secure random number):

> There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence
>   produced. In the past, some implementations of rand() have had serious
>   shortcomings in the randomness, distribution and period of the
>   sequence produced (in one well-known example, the low-order bit simply
>   alternated between 1 and 0 between calls).

You may obtain higher quality random generation using the [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library. But again, the generators used, such as for example the [mersene twister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_Twister#Disadvantages) is not sufficient for cryptographic use.

So you'd better go for specialized libraries such as [OpenSSL](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Random_Numbers).

Alternatively, given your platform choice, you can use the Windows API, with [`CryptGenRandom()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-cryptgenrandom) or, better, the newer [`BCryptGenRandom()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/bcrypt/nf-bcrypt-bcryptgenrandom).

Comment: I would try that